# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1416:17) react pdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf-viewer, react-pdf

I installed `react-pdf` but this is not working, giving error as given below screenshot.

[image]

I'm using [react-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf)

My Code:-

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';

function MyApp() {
  const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);

  function onDocumentLoadSuccess({ numPages }) {
    setNumPages(numPages);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Document file="somefile.pdf" onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}>
      </Document>
      <p>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: is this error occurring for all PDFs?

Comment: btw found this existing issue: https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/issues/1043

Comment: @riazosama yes...

Comment: not found any solution for this as you given solution URL @riazosama

Comment: Until the lib is fixed, you can explicitly transpile react-pdf from node_modules or find the appropriate dependency versions through `overrides` field in your package.json.

Comment: Any update on this issue? I am also getting the same error after updating react-pdf to latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
const pdfjs = require("pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.js")
```

Replacing:

```
const pdfjs = require("pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js")
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Doing this doesnt solve my problem.i had to downgrade my pdfjs-dist version to 2.6.347.After that the error is gone.But it is more advisable to upgrade the react version instead.